# Parse Xauthority file

Tags: awk

How can I parse the `Xauthority` file in Ubuntu. I tried something like this:

`cat /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority | awk -F'-' '{ print $2 }'`

According to the format, the first value should be user and the second the name of the terminal (machine) followed by the magic cookie. I only need the user name. In this case, it prints an empty string. How can I do this?

**EDIT**

At the beginning of the file, I also have the following string: `^A^@^@^R`. Will need to remove this as well I guess to get the user name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `xauth(1)` read it for you:

```
xauth list
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That worked. I was getting a little impatient that led me to cross-post.